# Outlook VBA how to save MailItem in custom object property

Tags: vba, class, outlook, mailitem

I'm trying to store a MailItem object in the property of my custom object to be recalled later, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
```

This is my Class1:

```
Private vprop1 As String
Private vprop2 As String
Private vprop3 As MailItem

Property Get prop1() As String
    prop1 = vprop1
End Property

Property Let prop1(aValue As String)
    vprop1 = aValue
End Property

Property Get prop2() As String
    prop2 = vprop2
End Property

Property Let prop2(aValue As String)
    vprop2 = aValue
End Property

Property Get prop3() As MailItem
    prop3 = vprop3
End Property

Property Let prop3(aValue As MailItem)
    vprop3 = aValue
End Property
```

This is my test. The error is referencing the third property assignment: `var.prop3 = ...`

```
Public Sub test()
    Set objsourcefolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim var As Class1
    Set var = New Class1

    var.prop1 = "\folder\sub\12345"
    var.prop2 = "Email subject regarding 12345"
    var.prop3 = objsourcefolder.Items.Item(objsourcefolder.Items.count)

    Debug.Print var.prop1
    Debug.Print var.prop2
    Debug.Print var.prop3
    Debug.Print var.prop3.Subject
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `MailItem` is an `object`, you have to set any variable referencing to it through the `Set` keyword and change `Property Let` (to be associated to not-`object` type properties) to `Property Set` (associated to `object` type properties)

Finally you can't use `Debug.Print var.prop3` since your `Class1` type hasn't any *default* property for its `prop3` `object` member

all what above results in:

---

class code

```
Private vprop1 As String '<--| vprop1 is declared as of 'String' type, i.e. NOT as an 'object'
Private vprop2 As String '<--| vprop2 is declared as of 'String' type, i.e. NOT as an 'object'
Private vprop3 As MailItem '<--| vprop3 is declared as of 'MailItem' type, i.e. as an 'object'

Property Get prop1() As String
    prop1 = vprop1
End Property

Property Let prop1(aValue As String)
    vprop1 = aValue
End Property

Property Get prop2() As String
    prop2 = vprop2
End Property

Property Let prop2(aValue As String)
    vprop2 = aValue
End Property

Property Get prop3() As MailItem
    Set prop3 = vprop3 '<--| use 'Se't keyword
End Property

Property Set prop3(aValue As MailItem) '<--| use 'Property Set' instead of 'Property Let'
    Set vprop3 = aValue '<--| use 'Set' keyword
End Property
```

---

test sub code

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim objsourcefolder As Folder
    Set objsourcefolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim var As Class1
    Set var = New Class1

    var.prop1 = "\folder\sub\12345"
    var.prop2 = "Email subject regarding 12345"
    Set var.prop3 = objsourcefolder.Items.Item(objsourcefolder.Items.Count)

    Debug.Print var.prop1
    Debug.Print var.prop2
'    Debug.Print var.prop3 '<--| this would result in an 438 error
    Debug.Print var.prop3.Subject
End Sub
```

Comment: it works! and i learned something! i have asked on a few other sites, and i was starting to lose hope that anyone on the internet knew about vba anymore, but here you send a beautiful answer in less than a day! this has made my day; thank you, kind stranger :)

Comment: You are welcome. I'd appreciate you could accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you!